# which one is suitable datastructure

Tags: data-structures

Two files each of size terabytes. A file comparison tool compares `i`th line of file1 with

`i` th line of file2. if they are same it prints. which datastructure is suitable.

1. B-tree
2. linked list
3. hash tables
4. none of them

Comment: This is obviously a homework question, so we will help you answer the question yourself. Can you think of any advantages/disadvantages of these solutions? Why would one method be fit and the others not?

Comment: obviously an in memory array would be best.  this allows you direct access to each line of the file.

Comment: This will give away the answer but I hate to see anyone struggle for too long :) The key to this question is the fact that the input files are _terabytes_ in size.

Comment: -1, because Title is not descriptive enough

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to buffer up at LEAST a line at a time. Here's one way:

```
While neither file is at EOF:
     Read lines A and B from files one and two (each)
     If lines are identical, print one of them
```

Translate into suitable programming language, and problem is solved.

Note that no fancy data structures are involved.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you can seek backwards in the file, you can compare a character at a time until you find EOL in both files (in which case you copy from mark to here onto output) or you find a mismatch, in which case you seek forward in each file while it's last character was not EOL. Then you reset your mark. Treat EOF as EOL, and you have buffered nothing but a couple of file offsets.

Answer (score 1):

the simple logic is read one line at a time from the file and match..
It's like

While line1 is not equal to EOF file1 and line2 is not equal to EOF file2:
Compare line1 and line2

Btw you have to be sure how much maximum character a line can contain so u can change buffer size accordingly..
Otherwise try bigdata concept spark framework to make your work easier.